# How do i resolve TimeZone issues in oracle 10 g?

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, oracle10g

My application makes use of 10g Oracle.

Oracle 10g has predefined set of timezones in a file called timezone.dat.

Not all timezones are included in it.

Because of this i am facing a issue saying

Error:

```
SQL-Exception - ORA-00604 error occured at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region not found
```

Patches for upgradation of timezone files need upgradation of oracle from 10g to higher versions.

How do i resolve this issue ?

Is there any alternative for this issue?

Comment: Which region is giving you that error? Are you sure it exists in exactly that form in later versions - maybe it just ha a slightly different name than you expect now? And which version do you think you need?

Comment: My version of the timezone file is **version 2** and timezone region 'Africa/Harare' is not included in this version. It is included in the **version 5** of the timezone file. My system timezone is set to 'Africa/Harare' which is (UTC/GMT)+2.There is GMT+2 in 10g , i tried changing the database as well as session timezone to GMT+2.It still gives the same error.

Comment: From MOS notes 412160.1 and 2069652.1 suggesting you need to upgrade before using the current data, from DSTv25. Do you have an issue with [the required patches](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=455862447289683&parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=412160.1&id=2069652.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=cfv3e0zwd_1313#aref_section315) or is there some other issue? In any case, this is more a question for [dba.se].

Comment: Time Zone  of  **Africa/Harare** - GMT+2. There is a timezone in 10g as GMT+2.If i change the database timezone and session timezone to GMT+2 . It doesnt work. But suppose for example if i use   **Africa/Cairo** (Included in 10g timezone file and whose timezone is also GMT+2) it works fine.Newer versions have **Africa/Harare** instead of GMT+2.What could be the reason ?

Comment: My previous comment was supposed to say that from those MOS notes I don't see anything suggesting you need to upgrade... I don't know why GMT+2 "doesn't work" and I don't have a 10g DB to experiment with. Why can't you apply the latest DST patch?

Comment: Africa/Harare does not apply any Daylight Saving Time, i.e. it is always UTC+02:00. So, why not using `SESSIONTIMEZONE = '+02:00'`?

Comment: I did , I tried changing SESSIONTIMEZONE and well as DBTIMEZONE to "+02:00".But still getting that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following statement in the database setup file

`-Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion = 'available_timezone'`

Alternate Solution:

`-Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion = false`

can be added  in the database set up file to bypass the timezone validation